# How to make circle shaped video player on Safari browser?

Tags: html, css, video, safari, cross-browser

I already made a circle shaped video with chrome and firefox with the css styles:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 100%;
-moz-border-radius: 100%;
border-radius: 100%;
```

When I opened it with Safari, it loads circle shapes first but when the video thumbnail is completely loaded and the video controls are shown, it became square.

I also tried making the parent `div` of the video circle and `overflow:hidden` but nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a YouTube embed to test with. Please clarify which platform your video is being hosted with or if you are embedding with an HTML5 `video` element.

It seems to have to do with the size of the video itself. I was able to replicate the issue only after decreasing the size of the video past a certain point. When the iframe gets too small, the video itself scales inside of it's own container separate from the controls. This seems to be the cause of `border-radius` not taking. Here are a couple of solutions, although slightly more convoluted than simply adding `border-radius: 100%` to the iframe.

---

One solution is to use SVG (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6wcdqg0x/1/) as SO doesn't want to show the video playing):

```css
svg {
    display: block;
    width: 560px;
    height: 315px;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <clippath id="circle">
      <circle r="120" cx="50%" cy="50%"></circle>
    </clippath>
  
    <g clip-path="url(#circle)">   
    <foreignObject width="560" x="0"
                y="0" height="315">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/QnxLau7m600?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </foreignObject>
   </g> 
</svg>
```

---

Another solution would be to to use a `-webkit-mask-image`:

```css
div { 
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
   <iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QnxLau7m600" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

You could also make this work in Firefox by using the `mask` property, but you will also need to use an SVG instead of a CSS gradient like `mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,...);` (this particular method uses a data URI). You will obviously have some work to do in terms of cross-browser compatibility.

---

That's all I've got for now. I'll report back if I can think of another solution.

Comment: I'm using HTML5 video tag.